How to change from root to a user in WSL
I am new at Linux so bear with me. When I open WSL on my Windows 10 machine, it used to open in my user directory, rich. Now it opens in root. I have tried the commands login and su - rich, but neither work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

the command seems correct stackexchange Q&A but is there a typo in the user name? (rich/richs)

I forgot to mention that this behavior started after I updated Ubuntu yesterday morning.  My user name is rich, so that's not the problem.  To the command sdo su - rich, the system responds:  su: user rich does not exist or the user entry does not contain all the required fields.  In Windows Explorer I can see /home/rich under Ubuntu-24.04 and I can move to the home subdirectory, but when I try to move to the rich subdirectory from home, the system responds No such file or directory.

I can't quite be sure why it changed for you, but if this happened to me, I would try the technique in my Super User answer.

I determined that my Windows file system now has two Ubuntu subdirectories under the Linux directory after I updated Ubuntu on October 30, one is Ubuntu in which I am not a user, and the other is Ubuntu-24.04 where I am a user. (I am listed as a user in /etc/passwd in the Ubuntu-24.04 directory and I can see my subdirectories.) Unfortunately running WSL opens the new(?) version of Ubuntu rather than my original Ubuntu-24.04 but I figured out how to open the Ubuntu-24.04 version in Powershell.
